# PHP multi dimensional Array removing partial duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array containing this

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Gold ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Sub2 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Sub2 [2] => Sub3 ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Sub2 [2] => Sub3 [3] => Sub4 ) 
[5] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Test ) 
)
```

How can i remove the array [2] [3] as they are existent in [4]

and the array would be like

```
Array (  
[0] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Gold )  
[1] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Sub2 [2] => Sub3 [3] => Sub4 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Sub1 [1] => Test ) 
)
```

Is it possible to automate?

Comment: use array_intersect http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php function

Comment: @Alex - From what I can see of array intersect it return only the values existing in multiple arrays, I want the opposite of that. to remove the repeated values, that already exist in the array.

Imagine it like a path or a url string like for example 
Sub1/Sub2 
Sub1/Sub2/Sub3 and 
Sub1/Sub2/Sub3/Sub4

Comment: [0] appears in all other ones too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($original as $orig_el) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($result as &$new_el) {
        if (count($orig_el) >= count($new_el) && array_slice($orig_el, 0, count($new_el)) == $new_el) {
            $new_el = $orig_el;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $result[] = $orig_el;
    }
}
```

Comment: The array stays the same after going through the code you gave here, I tried it and it outputs the same structure as the input.

Comment: Can you make a demo at IDEone.com?

Comment: Made the example, and it's working, I had a typo, Thank you so much!

here is the example btw [link](http://ideone.com/jYJ6xb)